# Access AWS S3 unauthenticated with Contigo IdentityPoolId, Error: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to setup connection to S3 via Angular application.

I did as written in this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html):

1. Create an Identity Pool
2. Configure Role Permissions

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

3. Configure CORS
4. Defining the Webpage

Add the SDK to the browser script

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.728.0.min.js"></script>
```

5. Configuring the SDK

```
const AWS = (window as any).AWS;
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:bla-bla-bla',
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: { Bucket: 'my-bucket' }
});
```

When I run this:

```
  s3.listObjects({ Delimiter: '/' }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
      }
    });
```

I see in the AWS console that there is a connection:
[image]

But still get the error: `Error CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

`message: "Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool." __type: "InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException"`

What am I missing here? I thought  `IdentityPoolId` is all that is needed